# Tracing subject sentence and missing classifier

Tags: grammar, counters, particle-を, subjects

In the following sentence I am not sure if the subject is 始末したコボルト or not. I guess it is the subject and not the group in which is plunged searching for shelter. Is it correct?

> 始末したコボルトを盾にするように群へと突っ込み、二匹のコボルトを巻き込んで地面に倒れ込む
>
> “The goblin of which I got rid throws himself into the group in search of shelter and collapses to the ground, dragging with him two goblins.”

This is the other sentence with a problem for me:

> 今、四匹目を腹をかっさばいて残るは二
>
> “Now, I break the fourth belly and remain two.”

If my interpretation is correct, why is 二 not followed by the 匹 classifier?

Comment: Next time you ask, please ask only one thing per question, and provide more context. A few sentences before the sentence in question would greatly help people understand the context.

Answer (score 1):

を is an ***object*** marker, of course! The subject of this sentence is someone who killed the goblin, which is omitted and not shown in this excerpt. Assuming the omitted subject as "I"...

> 始末したコボルトを盾にするように群へと突っ込み、二匹のコボルトを巻き込んで地面に倒れ込む。
>   I rushed into the crowd (as if I were) using the goblins I killed as a shield, and collapsed on the ground dragging two goblins.

- ～を盾にする = "use ～ as a shield". In general, `AをBにする` can mean "use A as B", "turn A into B", "make A B" etc. See ２㋒ in [this entry](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/120514/meaning/m0u/))
- ように = as if

> If my interpration is correct, why 二 is not followed by the 匹 classifier?

The second counter is simply omitted because there's no need to repeat it again.