# What is "舎弟" supposed to mean in this context?

Tags: translation, meaning, syntax, suffixes

Speaker A tells speaker B that he feels like he's seen her before, speaker B responds with:

> あんたアレでしよ？哲也兄がこっちで舎弟にしたっていう

And speaker A replies:

> 哲也兄！ ？ っていうか俺そういう扱いなの！？舎弟って、俺あのハゲに兄貴分らしい事何一つされてないんですけど！？

What I'm confused about is why does speaker A call Tetsuya "哲也兄" - Tetsuya nii when the 兄 suffix is used for older brothers but then she says Tetsuya is her younger brother "舎弟", there's something I'm misunderstanding here but I can't pinpoint what. My best guess is that I'm probably misinterpreting 舎弟, which could have another meaning that's not in a dictionary and doesn't literally mean younger brother?

I would be grateful if someone could point out and explain where I'm going wrong, thank you!

Comment: Do you understand that "she says Tetsuya is her younger brother 舎弟" by the phrase 哲也兄がこっちで舎弟にしたっていう or by some other context that is not written here?

Comment: The conversation between A and B in Japanese is very simple. But your explanation besides the conversation seems to make the interpretation in Japanese confused.

Comment: In "Speaker A tells speaker B that he feels like he's seen her before", is it correct that speaker A = he and speaker B = she?

Comment: @mackygoo I interpreted that he is her younger brother from the sentence I gave above "哲也兄がこっちで舎弟にしたっていう" am I wrong in assuming that he is her younger brother from this line?

Comment: @mackygoo ah yes my explanation is confusing because I am very confused by this simple Japanese conversation unfortunately. Also that's correct Speaker A = he B = she

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have missed several points.

- Despite what jisho.org says, AFAIK 舎弟 is never used to refer to one's blood-related younger brother in modern Japanese. Here 舎弟 means someone's subordinate/disciple/pupil/follower/etc. It's mainly regarded as gangster jargon today, although it may be more like a casual [弟分](http://jisho.org/word/%E5%BC%9F%E5%88%86) in this context.
- You seem to have failed to recognize the [`～にする` construction](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/32807/5010). (～を)舎弟にする means "to take on someone as a disciple".
- Speaker A said "哲也兄!?", but that does not mean he *calls* Tetsuya that way. Speaker A just repeated in a surprised tone what speaker B said.

My translation attempt (although not literal):

> B: あんたアレでしよ？ 哲也兄がこっちで舎弟にしたっていう
>   B: So, you're the person Tetsuya-nii took on as a disciple here.
>   B: Oh, I think I know you. Tetsuya-nii said he took on you as a disciple in this place.
>
> A: 哲也兄!?
>   A: (You said) Tetsuya-*nii*!? (i.e., Wow, is Tetsuya your older brother?)
>
> A: っていうか俺そういう扱いなの!?
>   A: Wait, is that the way I'm supposed to be treated!? (i.e., Do you mean someone said I am a disciple of Tetsuya?)
>
> A: 舎弟って、俺あのハゲに[兄貴分](http://jisho.org/word/%E5%85%84%E8%B2%B4%E5%88%86)らしい事何一つされてないんですけど!?
>   A: What the heck is "disciple"? That bald bastard did nothing for me like a leader!

Answer (score 1):

This sentence has some yakuza(Japanese Mafia) terms.

Yakuza treat their member as a family, so they use family words like 弟、兄, etc.

舎弟 is like a young brother for superior yakuza, 舎弟 call his superior yakuza　兄貴 or ～兄.

Answer (score 1):

To interpret the OP's question, I perfectly agree with Yuuichi Tam's understanding of the background of the given phrases.

Yuuichi Tam said:

> This sentence has some yakuza (Japanese Mafia) terms.
> Yakuza treat their member as a family, so they use family words like 弟、兄, etc.
> 舎弟 is like a young brother for superior yakuza, 舎弟 call his superior yakuza　兄貴 or ～兄.

In my understanding, 舎弟 is a younger brother-in-yakuza's-law just like to say a younger brother-in-law who is not related by blood. Same as 舎弟, 兄 or 兄貴 is an elder brother-in-yakuza's-law in the given phrases.

In my answer I am going to call 哲也兄 "***the boss Tetsuya***" instead of "***the elder brother-in-yakuza's-law Tetsuya***", and am going call 舎弟 "***an underling***" instead of "***a younger brother-in-yakuza's law***".

I'm going to tell another reason why 兄 in 哲也兄 does not imply a real brother of the speaker B later on.

> あんたアレでしよ？哲也兄がこっちで舎弟にしたっていう

This phrase is an inversion of

> あんた（は）、哲也兄がこっちで舎弟にしたっていうアレでしょ？

こっちで implies こっちで勝手に, and こっちで literally means ***here*** and acutually it means ***from 哲也兄's side***, and 勝手に means *(to do something) without one's permission*.
アレ is literally ***that***, and in this phrase, it implies ***the man on the topic***.
As a whole, the given sentence could be interpreted like:
*Are you the man whom 哲也兄 **boss Tetsuya** made his 舎弟 **underling** by himself without your permission?*

> 哲也兄！ ？ っていうか俺そういう扱いなの！？舎弟って、俺あのハゲに兄貴分らしい事何一つされてないんですけど！？

is roughly devided into two phrases:

> 1. 哲也兄！ ？ っていうか俺そういう扱いなの！？舎弟って、
> 2. 俺あのハゲに兄貴分らしい事何一つされてないんですけど！？

哲也兄！ *What!? Is Tetsuya my boss!?*
っていうか is と言｛い｝うか *if I say in other words*. そういう points to 舎弟って（＝ 舎弟という） in this phrase.

The phrase 1 is interpreted like:

> 哲也「兄」とは何ですか！　哲也から俺を見ると、俺は哲也の舎弟という扱いなの！

*What!? Is Tetsuya my boss!? He takes me for his underling!*

> 俺あのハゲに兄貴分らしい事何一つされてないんですけど！？

ハゲ is a word to be used to insult a person who is bald. In this phrase Tetsuya seems bald.
The whole meaning of 2 is like:
*I haven't been given anything that seems a favor from a boss from the bald bastard, (so I wouldn't like to consider Tetsuya is my boss)*.

#### The final answer:

I think Tetsuya is not the speaker B's or her older brother but is also her boss or something like that, because the speaker A called Tetsuya ハゲ in her presence. You can't insult a ***yakuza*** in the presence of his real sister even if the speaker A does not accept himself as an underling of Tetsuya.